# Null razor viewmodel passing nullity check(!)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Maybe I'm just too tired but I've never seen this happen before.

I just uploaded my MVC 5 Web application to our (to be) production server (Amazon AWS) and there's this razor view that's returning a `NullReferenceException` for the viewmodel `IEnumerable<CardViewModel>` when I try to loop thru it's contents in a foreach. It would be Ok for it to be null and that's why it has a nullity check right above the foreach that's raising the exception:

[image]

I've tried and I can't reproduce it locally. Any clues?

Comment: afaik, you can add a breakpoint in the view. You can also check if there are anything null before passing the data to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the error message shows line 19 as erroneous, my guess is that it's the `RegionAcronim` string that is null and invoking its `ToLower()` method throws the error.

Try this:

```
<div id="@(card.RegionAcronim != null ? card.RegionAcronim.ToLower() : String.Empty)">
```

Comment: I really hope it's something like this or else I'll have nightmares with it later tonight. I'm pretty sure ``RegionAcronim`` can't be null but it might be some other property in that same line (I've cut the image but there's more code there).

Comment: The rest of the properties shown in the image don't seem to be nullable so I chose `RegionAcronim`.

Comment: In the end, the problem was caused by lazy loading, the Model wasn't null until I enumerated it. Since this answer helped me find the error, I'm accepting it.